# How can I minimise the code needed to run this custom function?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'd like to shorten one of my scripts and I got na idea but I dont know how to do that.
Have a piece of code like this:

```
COMMAND="find /etc -type "
case $1:
 "directory") $COMMAND d
 ;;
esac
```

Of course this is the short version :) And now I want to be able to shorten it, not towrite that $COMMAND everywhere, so I would like to have something like this:

```
$COMMAND <the case statement return value>
```

but I dont want to use a variable to store the result of case.

Thanks :) Hope you understood what I want :D

EDIT 1:
Its possible to create a function and pass the find parameter as $1 as pointed by Serg.
Now, IF I wanted to do it just without the function, im sure there's a way :D Not like Serg didnt solve it, I'm just curious :D

Comment: Turn it into a function and pass type as $1 argument, then issue call to function in case statements. I am on mobile so cannot post well formated answer , so maybe someome else can ir i will do it in about an hour or si

Comment: Thats a nice idea. It solves my problem, thank you :)

Comment: Posted an answer. Please mark it as accepted if you found that it solves your problem. Thank you in advance and ask more questions on the site ! :)

Comment: Adding an edit to simplify the answer. The function approach is standard, but in your specific question, this will work

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an `alias` here?

Comment: @underscore_d that's a good solution  that shortens the code.  I'd suggest you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several possible ways to simplify the code. Below are the solutions ordered by the amount of code:

1. `printf` and parameter substitution (no error checking)
2. `xargs` and parameter substitution (no error checking)
3. `find` and parameter substition only (no error checking)
4. fall-through case structure (Solves error checking issue )
5. Test logic, xargs, and parameter substitution
6. Bash function
7. Array, for-loop, test, and &&

---

1. **`printf` and parameter substitution solution**

   A little known quality of the `printf` function is that if you call `printf "%c" someString`, it will print only the *first* character of that string. Thus, we can avoid using case statement with parameter expansion and `printf` like so:

   ```
   xieerqi:$ cat someScript.sh
   #!/bin/bash
   find /etc -type $(printf "%c" $1 )
   ```

   now execute:

   ```
   xieerqi:$ sudo ./someScript.sh  directory | head
   [sudo] password for xieerqi: 
   /etc
   /etc/logrotate.d
   /etc/apm
   /etc/apm/event.d
   /etc/apm/scripts.d
   /etc/apm/resume.d
   /etc/apm/suspend.d
   /etc/speech-dispatcher
   /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules
   /etc/speech-dispatcher/clients
   ```

   A limitation here is that we're forking a process to call `printf`, which the function solution avoids - function and case structure are all native bash tools.
2. **`xargs` and parameter substitution**

   Using bash's parameter substitution we can chop off a substring from a variable (for example `${VAR:0:3}` gives first 3 characters of `VAR`); in this case we want the first character for a type `directory` or `file`.  Then we can use `xargs` to pass that as parameter to `find`

   ```
   echo ${1:0:1} | xargs -I {} find /etc -type  {}
   ```

   The `find` man page mentions that for `-type` flag on Solaris there is something known as a door file, which is represented by the capital letter `D`, but since we're on Linux, we can say this is a limitation that is reasonable to ignore.

   However, there is another danger in this code - if a user enters `flower` as the `$1` parameter, this is still going to search for `-type f`, because we take first char of any string … In other words, **there's no error checking**.
3. **`find` with parameter expansion**

   Taking parameter expansion even further, we can do this:

   ```
    find /etc -type ${1:0:1}
   ```

   Basically , a one-liner with `find` command and a substring of the `$1` variable. **Also, no error-checking**.
4. **Fall-through case structure**

   The big issue with the last three methods is the error checking. They are good when you trust the user not to be a dummy, or just writing code for yourself. Now, in Java it's possible to write a `switch` statement that will run the same command for multiple cases if you just omit the `break` command. In `bash` that can be done as well with `;&` terminator. Quote from `man bash`

   > Using `;&` in place of `;;` causes execution to continue with the list associated with the next set of patterns.

   All we have to do is test for the types, like "directory", "file", "block" and so on, and then use parameter substitution to chop off the first character. Like so

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   case "$1" in
     "directory") ;&
     "file");&
     "block") find /etc -type  ${1:0:1} ;;
     *) exit 1 ;;
   esac
   ```

5.**Test logic, xargs, and parameter substitution**

```
 Basic idea here is that we're sending $1 variable through pipe to `xargs`, which in turn substitutes it into test (again square brackets). `xargs` in turn builds the actual command that runs by replacing `{}` with whatever was passed to `xargs`.  As for test command, it's simple or statement,  `EXPRESSION -o EXPRESSION ` , where we test if string $1 is equal to either "file" or "directory string"

    echo "$1" | xargs -I {}  [ "{}" = "file" -o "{}" = "directory"  ] \
    && find /etc -type ${1:0:1}

 `xargs` is really useful when you need to process multiple argumens with the same command. Considering that in this case we only have one argument that needs to be processed with the same command , this can be simplified to

    [ "$1" = "file" -o "$1" = "directory"  ] && find /etc -type ${1:0:1} 

Of course the big limitation is that if you test for more than one type, you need longer `[ EXPR1 -o EXPR2 ]` structure with multiple `-o` parts.
```

6. **Function solution**

   `find` command can be placed into a function, which then can be called with positional parameters.

   For instance:

   ```
   function findStuff
   {
    find /etc -type "$1" 
   }
   ```

   Here's a small demo. Notice I am using `sudo` because for a lot of files in `/etc` regular users don't have read permissions

   ```
   xieerqi:$ sudo ./someScript.sh directory | head                                            
   [sudo] password for xieerqi: 
   /etc
   /etc/logrotate.d
   /etc/apm
   /etc/apm/event.d
   /etc/apm/scripts.d
   /etc/apm/resume.d
   /etc/apm/suspend.d
   /etc/speech-dispatcher
   /etc/speech-dispatcher/modules
   /etc/speech-dispatcher/clients

   xieerqi:$ sudo ./someScript.sh file | head                                                 
   [sudo] password for xieerqi: 
   /etc/hosts.deny
   /etc/logrotate.d/speech-dispatcher
   /etc/logrotate.d/pm-utils
   /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
   /etc/logrotate.d/yate
   /etc/logrotate.d/apport
   /etc/logrotate.d/apt
   /etc/logrotate.d/consolekit
   /etc/logrotate.d/fail2ban
   /etc/logrotate.d/cups-daemon

   xieerqi:$ cat someScript.sh                                                                
   #!/bin/bash
   function findStuff
   {
    find /etc -type "$1" 
   }

   case "$1" in 
     "directory")findStuff d ;;
     "file") findStuff f;;
   esac
   ```
7. **Array, for-loop, test, and &&**

   Basic idea here - match user's input against a list, and if matched do something. We create an array of items to check for, have a test condition (square brackets by the way are alias to `test` command), and just run a loop to test the $1 variable. `&&` operator allows executing command if and only if what's on the left of `&&` was successful. So if we found a string that's in the array, we execute find command. The ${1:0:1} was discussed in previous examples - parameter expansion that chops - off the first character from our matched type. So this solution has error checking and whole-lot of code packed into just 3 lines (4 if you include `#!` line).

   ```
   #!/bin/bash   
   array=("file" "directory" "block");
   for TYPE in "${array[@]}"; do 
      [ "$1" = "$TYPE"  ] && find /etc/ -type ${1:0:1}; 
   done
   ```

Comment: +1 for being so comprehensive and including a lot of additional concerns way beyond what was asked (but very important)

Answer (score 4):

Put it into a function:

```
MyFind () {
  COMMAND="find /etc -type "
  case $1:
   "directory") $COMMAND d
   ;;
  esac
}
```

Now you can always use it as `MyFind $TYPE`

---

#### Regarding your 1st comment

You can also put only the case statement into a function

```
FType () {
  case $1 in
    "directory") echo d;;
    "file") echo f;;
  esac
}

COMMAND="find /etc -type "
$COMMAND $(FType $TYPE)
```

Comment: I know I can go like case:
"something") $Command d
something command l
something command s

but Id like to avoid writing command all the time . Is there a way to do it like: $COMMAND {the case statement} ?

Answer (score 2):

```
[[ "$1" == "directory" ]] && find /etc -type d
```

Comment: Yes, a possible solution, hence upvoted, but that means OP has to write multiple lines like this  to check multiple types. For example to check for all types listed in `find` man page, that would be 8 lines code. This may work for simple scripts, but for complex scripts may be redundant and `case ...esac` structure would be preferred, besides it does the same job.  Main point though is that OP wanted to *write find command one time*, and just give letter as argument to sort of "standard" find command, in other words simplify the process.   Nonethelss, I like your answer

Comment: Side note: there's no need to enclose variables containing whitespaces in double quotes in `[[]]` (and strings without whitespaces regardless): `[[ $1 == directory ]] [...]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
declare -A foo    # associative array

foo["directory"]="d"
foo["file"]="f"
foo["link"]="l"

find /etc -type ${foo["$1"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another idea to add to the already wide set of options from Serg's excellent answer.

You might be able to use an `alias` for this - possibly with some slight changes to how you currently do things.

An `alias` is simply a word that you choose to map to a larger string, which the shell will expand whenever it encounters it. Perhaps the most commonly seen use case is to apply 'defaults' to an existing command, like this:

```
alias ls='ls -a --color=auto'
```

However, there's no requirement that your `alias` has to be named after an existing command - or even shorter than its destination pattern - so you could e.g. `alias tgzcreator='tar -czvf'`

`alias`es share lifetime with the shell in which they are defined. 'Persistent' `alias`es for you can be set up in `~/.bash_aliases`, which *should* be sourced automatically by most well-written default `.bashrc` scripts and suchlike.

Note a couple of hints:

- Rather than worrying in a particular script whether a previously defined `alias` will interfere with your code, you can prefix it with a backslash to ensure `alias`ing is skipped. e.g. I normally `alias` `cp` to `cp -i` to avoid accidentally overwriting things, but in some scripts, I clearly *want* to overwrite things. (I'm not going to use some awful workaround like setting up a known un`alias`ed user!) So, in that script, I'll use `\cp src dst`
- `alias`es may not be sourced by default within shell scripts, which launch their own non-interactive copy of the shell. You can ensure they are expanded by setting the option `expand_aliases` in your script. I got this from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197461/how-to-set-an-alias-inside-a-bash-shell-script-so-that-is-it-visible-from-the-ou

So, basing off the limited context available in your post, you might want to do something *kinda* like this:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias get_etc_dir='find /etc -type d'
alias get_etc_fil='find /etc -type f'
```

For you, this may not work without tweaking, e.g. changing your parameterised inode type into a per-alias suffix. It's just another option for how users can shorten bits of code in general. Either way, I've tried to explain comprehensively based on what I know, and I hope it's useful somewhere.

(Also, I'd suggest moving this to Unix/Linux SE, assuming that's the ideal for things that aren't Ubuntu-specific?)

Comment: Very nice. I would simplify this even further : alias expands to a string, just like assigning it to a variable. So doing `alias findStuff='find /etc/ -type` and then calling it with `findStuff d` would work.  Not sure if that would work in a script though, as I've never used aliases in scripts, mostly functions

Comment: True. When I said it didn't natively support the same parameterisation as the original `$COMMAND`, I meant the conditional contraction of the `directory` parameter into just `d`. That should probably be done using just one of your methods, rather than adding `alias` into the mix too! But yes, of course, if you just want the literal parameter, simply type it after.